# ¿Como puedo hacer que el for retorne la cantidad de veces que estaba repetida una lista en otra? por ejemplo:

Tags: python, bucle-for

```
a = [[1],[2],['hola'],[4],[2, 4], [2, 4]]
b = [2, 4]
i = 0
for i in a:
   if i == b:
      print("hola")
```

> quiero que en este caso me retorne el numero '2', ya que el [2 , 4] esta repetido 2 veces en 'a'

Answer (score 2):

Las listas python tienen el método `.count()` para contar cuántas veces se repite el elemento que le pases como parámetro.

En este caso por tanto sería tan simple como:

```
print(a.count(b))  # Muestra 2
```

Esto es más rápido que cualquier bucle que puedas escribir, pues aunque internamente ejecuta un bucle también, ese está programado en C y compilado a código máquina en la forma más eficiente posible.

Answer (score 1):

Una solución pythonesca:

```
a = [[1],[2],['hola'],[4],[2, 4], [2, 4]]
b = [2, 4]
print(sum(1 for x in a if x == b))
```

La expresión `for x in a` va recorriendo todos los elementos de la lista `a`. A cada elemento se aplica la condición `if x == b`. Si la condición se cumple, se genera un 1. Si no, no se genera nada.

Luego es cosa de sumar todos los unos recolectados en el recorrido y tienes el número de veces que aparece la sublista.

Comment: Aún más breve (y críptico) aprovechando que un booleano true equivale al entero 1 y el false al 0: `sum(x==b for x in a)`

Answer (score 0):

Tienes despistado para qué es la variale `i = 0`.

Como es un contador la llamamos `cont` y luego le sumas 1 cuando cumple el `if`.

```
a = [[1],[2],['hola'],[4],[2, 4], [2, 4]]
b = [2, 4]

cont = 0
for i in a:
   if i == b:
      cont += 1

print(cont)
```

Como estás con **python** la solución de @CandidMoe con una comprension de lista es más rápida y elegante.